# Dynamically Change Background Color of the Page on timer after Page load in windows phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-7.1.1

how to dynamically Change Background Color of the Page on timer after Page load in windows phone 7. Suppose there are 4-5 colors that need to be change after particular time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) for this operation.

Use the method below in your page and call it from `PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded` event.
Suppose you have to change background color every 5 seconds,

```
private void ChangeBackgroundColor()
{
    DispatcherTimer dt = new DispatcherTimer();
    dt.Interval = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000);

    dt.Tick += (s, e) =>
    {
        //Code for change background color 
    };

    dt.Start();
}
```

This will process every 5 seconds.